# package.json scripts that work with npm and yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I am using [npm as a build tool](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/) and so in my `package.json`, and some of my scripts depend on other scripts:

```
{
  "test": "npm run lint && mocha"
}
```

This hardcodes the `npm` package manager into `package.json`. How can make this approach to expressing dependencies work with both `npm` and `yarn`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `$npm_execpath` environment variable refers to the build tool, so just replace `npm` with the `$npm_execpath`:

```
{
  "test": "$npm_execpath run lint && mocha"
}
```

Both `npm test` and `yarn test` will work, and will use the appropriate build tool.

**Note!** This would NOT work on Windows machines.

Comment: This has been working great for me up until I had to work on a Windows machine at work. Where I get the error `'$npm_execpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command` does anyone know how to get this to work on Windows? I'm somewhat clueless when it comes to that operating system.

Comment: @rgb Uh, you might be out of luck on Windows, I don't know how things work there.

Comment: If `$npm_execpath` contains spaces, things may break if you don't surround the variable with double quotes. E.g `"test": "\"$npm_execpath\" run lint && mocha"`

Comment: Windows might work with `%npm_execpath%` instead, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Tested on Windows. `%npm_execpath%` works, indeed. However in cross-platform setup it becomes an unsupportable mess.

Answer (score 11):

While mjs' answer is great, there's also a small package that is purported to work on all environments including Windows: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarpm

To use in a project, run `yarn add yarpm --dev` / `npm i -D yarpm` and then just use yarpm in your scripts like this:

```
{
  "test": "yarpm run lint && mocha"
}
```

As the package README notes, you just need to make sure your commands would be suitable for passing through to *either* yarn or npm: you cannot use arguments/flags that only work on one package manager.

Comment: Great suggestion. yarpm is currently unsupported, yarn-or-npm is a recent alternative.