# Calling one script from another with Yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

Below is an example how to run a script from another with `npm` in `package.json`.

What's the equivalent with `yarn`?

```
{
  "name": "npm-scripts-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm scripts example",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist && mkdir dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean",

  }
}
```

Comment: `"prebuild": "yarn run clean",` and then `yarn run prebuild` should work no ? You could just do `yarn run clean` tho

Comment: Because I tested with `"scripts": {"test": "yarn -v", "test2": "yarn run test" }` and then `yarn run test2` worked just fine. Also according to https://yarnpkg.com/lang/fr/docs/cli/run/ yarn run should just works with any scripts in the script section of the package.json

Comment: I'm sorry, you're 100 % right. Don't know why it didn't work for me initially.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you :)

Comment: Consider utilizing [yarpm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarpm) if you want your scripts to run with either npm or yarn. For instance: `"prebuild": "yarpm run clean"` You can also use the `$npm_execpath` environment variable on _*nix_  - as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647961/package-json-scripts-that-work-with-npm-and-yarn). For instance `"prebuild": "$npm_execpath run clean",`. However, windows cmd.exe references variables using the `%...%` syntax - for instance `"prebuild": "%npm_execpath% run clean"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do

```
{
  "name": "npm-scripts-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm scripts example",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist && mkdir dist",
    "prebuild": "yarn run clean",

  }
}
```

And then the command `yarn run prebuild`should work.
Also you could just do `yarn run clean`.

Documentation of the `run` cli : https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/

Answer (score 9):

Improving on [@l-faros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7337055/l-faros) answer, Yarn also supports a shorter syntax

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist && mkdir dist",
    "prebuild": "yarn clean",

  }
}
```

and `yarn prebuild` to run the script command.

The syntax allows one to omit the `run` argument.
Documentation: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/#toc-user-defined-scripts